# Android SQLite database exception

Tags: android, sql, eclipse, sqlite

Currently having an issue in my SQLite database in android, when I try and run a comparison I get the following error:
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "@hotmail": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _id, userName, password FROM userTable WHERE userName=djdss@hotmail.comAND password=shshsh

my search is:

public boolean getUserNameAndPassword(String userName, String Password) throws SQLException {

```
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,USER,
                    PWD},USER + "=" + userName + "AND password=" + Password, null,
                    null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor.getCount() > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;}
```

My attempt to run it is:

```
  boolean signIn = dbHelper.getUserNameAndPassword(mEmail, mPassword);
        if (signIn){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Sign in successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Sign in failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is exactly why you should use `selectionArgs` and `?`.

Answer (score 2):

You should used a parameterized queries instead of just appending in the username and password variables, see the example below:

```
Cursor mCursor =
        db.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,USER,
                PWD},USER + " = ? AND password = ?", new String[]{ userName, Password },
                null, null, null, null);

if (mCursor.getCount() > 0)
{
    return true;
}
return false;}
```

Comment: You should also remove the password appending from the query :)

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the prompt response, I have changed to what you have said but I am still getting:
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "example": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _id, userName, password FROM userTable WHERE userName = ? AND password = ?example

Comment: i dont see where the word 'example' is getting into the query.

Comment: It is part of the two text entry fields and once they are entered clicking the sign in button fires them in.
mEmail = mEmailView.getText().toString();
mPassword = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

Comment: @NiekHaarman good catch, copy and paste malfunction i think :)  Try now.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT DISTINCT _id, userName, password FROM userTable WHERE userName=djdss@hotmail.comAND password=shshsh`

You forgot a space between `userName` and `AND`.

Furthermore, have a look at John's answer about parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a space, try now:

```
Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,USER,
                    PWD},USER + "='" + userName + "' AND password='" + Password + "'", null,
                    null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor.getCount() > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;}
```

Edit: Also, you should think about using parameterized queries as John proposes.

Comment: Hi there, with your solution I get the following error:
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "@hdjsj": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _id, userName, password FROM userTable WHERE userName=djsjsjs@hdjsj.com AND password=sjsjsj

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,USER,
                    PWD},USER+"='"+userName+"' AND password='"+Password+"'", null,
                    null, null, null, null);
```